# Call to undefined method App::uses() - cakephp - CakeEmail

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am trying to setup CakeEmail to use my gmail as my isp blocks port 25.

However, I am having a very frustrating problem trying to load the App::uses class.

I have tried placing it in many different locations and I still get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method App::uses() in C:\www\ash\app\controllers\songrequests_controller.php on line 3
```

I am not sure whats going on. Am I not loading something properly, or am I not placing it in the correct place?

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
class SongrequestsController extends AppController {
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Thanks for any help.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App::uses()` is a method introduced in CakePHP 2.x, whereas it seems like you are using CakePHP 1.x, hence the error.

So you either have to upgrade to CakePHP 2.x (which I recommend) or use CakePHP 1.x's approach for sending emails described in http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1283/Email.

Comment: Well that is def it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just an update. I upgraded to the latest stable version. (That was a blast of fun..) and I have the email function working again.

Thanks Again!